# Preventing map move on zoom in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, zoom

How to prevent the map from moving when a user zooms in with scrollwheel?

I would like the center to be preserved in any case.

```
var mymap = L.map('spotmap', {
   dragging: false
}).setView(spot_LatLng, 18);

var marker = L.marker(spot_LatLng).addTo(mymap);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `scrollWheelZoom` option to `'center'` when defining map:

```
var mymap = L.map('spotmap', {
   dragging: false,
   scrollWheelZoom: 'center'
}).setView(spot_LatLng, 18);
```

Comment: In the doc : Whether the map can be zoomed by using the mouse wheel. If passed 'center', it will zoom to the center of the view regardless of where the mouse was. 
Thank you very much @TomazicM